# roles and permissions in WSO2 and ANGULAR

Tags: angular, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating an application with Angular and using the authentication provider with WSO2, when logging in from the application getting the following in the console: 
[respuesta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8vsi.png)

I want to make the users who access my application have the necessary permissions, for example: I have a price list on a route, this list can only be edited by a person who has the edit: price permission, if the user has this permission the application allows the user to edit the price list. How can I get this type of permission when I log in with WSO2?

Answer (score 1):

Your application level permissions should not be defined/stored in the WSO2 side. Rather, you can create some roles on WSO2 side. (No need to assign any permission to these roles) Ex. `editorRole` `managerRole`

You can then assign your users to their respective roles from the WSO2 Identity Server.

When you authenticate, you can get the authenticated user's roles(not permissions, roles.) in the ID_TOKEN.

Your application logic should decode the received token and take the decision whether to allow or not a particular operation, by checking the roles claim of the token.

To make that decision, you application logic needs to have a mapping of `WSO2_ROLE` against your `APPLICATION_OPERATIONS`. (Or against the `APPLICATION_PERMISSIONS`)